# How can I alias to `!!` (last command)?

Tags: bash, command-history, alias

`!!` in bash runs last command. I find it too difficult to type given how much I use it. `alias` to the rescue, I presumed.

Or not. I tried:

```
$ alias dl='!!'               # Aliasing
$ echo Testing123             # Here's something to test on
Testing123
$ dl                          # Testing alias
bash: !!: command not found
$                             # I AM DISAPPOINT
```

Without quotes also fails.

What's up?

Comment: Aliases usually shorten the length of frequently typed commands, or adding frequently used switches. What's the point of even needing an alias for !!?

Comment: @bdowning, presumably so you don't have to hit Shift and reach up in the corner of the keyboard.

Comment: @bdowning As cjm; my Shift-finger wants a break.

Comment: Get a dvorak. qwerty stair-step keyboards are an anachronism left over from typewriters designed to slow you down and make you hands hurt. After 20 years of emacs, my fingers are like pretzels

Comment: @bdowning I've considered dvorak and colemak, but I move between multiple computers daily and qwerty is the unfortunate hardware standard. All those C-chords on Emacs are little reasons I prefer vim. :-)

Comment: @bdowning: [according to *"Why QWERTY was invented"*, slowing you down was not a design objective of querty, but *reducing clashes*](http://home.earthlink.net/~dcrehr/whyqwert.html) (of course, keyboards don't clash at all, so other layouts might be more favourable)

Comment: @sr_ The clashes occurred because of the speed of typists. If you wish to continue this I suggest we move to a chat room. I don't care to continue, the less typing the better :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
alias dl='fc -s'
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-History-Builtins

Comment: Works! Still curious though: What makes `!!` un-aliasable?

Comment: I can't find anything quickly in [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) but I'm guessing that bash performs any history expansions *before* substituting aliases. So the shell only sees the command "!!" which clearly doesn't exist.