# How to use the last command in the while loop?

Tags: bash, command-history

I am wondering how to modify this code.

```
ls
while [ 1 > 0 ]
do
fc -s
sleep 1
done
```

For `fc -s`, you can refer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33794/how-can-i-alias-to-last-command) for details.

My question are as follows:

1. How will it run? If you name it as `test.sh`.
2. If I want `fc -s` represent the first line `ls`, how will I modify it? That is to say, I want to Run `ls` then sleep one second, then `ls`, then sleep one second,... Of course `ls` may be placed by some other command.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux!  Could you try elaborating your explanations a bit of what you're asking? I wasn't able to follow what your questions are? Specifically with #2.

Comment: @slm Is it more clearly?

Comment: What does it imply: "`ls` may be placed by some other command."

Comment: @unxnut AVERYVERYVERYLONGCOMMAND for example.

Comment: *"I want to Run ls then sleep one second, then ls, then sleep one second,..."* The answer to this is `watch`. No need to make your own.

Comment: `watch` is such a powerful tool that I cannot control the output. @MichaelKjörling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something along the lines of this:

```
 $ cat script.sh
 while sleep 1
 do
     eval "$@"
 done
 $ ls
 $ sh script.sh !!
```

The script will run the command passed to it over and over again. `!!` evaluates to the last command.

---

If you want the command to be part of the script and don't want to type it in multiple locations, try this:

```
 $ cat script.sh
 cmd=ls
 while sleep 1
 do
     eval "$cmd"
 done
 $ sh script.sh
```

Comment: This can quite easily break -- reparsing with `eval` is almost always a bad idea. http://sprunge.us/TMij

Comment: @ChrisDown: It's definitely not ideal. That particular problem can be fixed by removing the `eval` statement. (`s/eval "$@"/"$@"/`).

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use the watch command, which does exactly what you want?
This is what it says in the manual:

> watch - execute a program periodically, showing output fullscreen

To run the command every second:

```
watch -n 1 command
```

Comment: Yes, but how to get the command before the `while loop`?

Comment: You need to be more specific here. What is this script good for?

Comment: I need to a command like `watch`. But I don't want it presented fullscreen. I want all output shows again and again in the terminal. And knowing how to get the command before the `while loop` is another problem which is not as important.

Comment: #/!bin/bash
while true;
do
     $1
     sleep 1
done

save this as test.sh, make it executable and execute ist e.g. test.sh ls

Comment: `#/!bin/bash <br/>
while true <br/>
do <br/>
     $1 <br/>
     sleep 1<br/>
done`

Comment: @user2516278: You should add that to your answer.

Comment: @Evan having probs with the new line in code tag :-(

Comment: @user2516278: Prepend code lines with four spaces. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks.